# Python: subprocess.call and variants fail for a particular application from executed .py but not from python in CLI

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a strange issue here - I have an application that I'm attempting to launch from python, but all attempts to launch it from within a .py script fail without any discernable output. Testing from within VSCode debugger. Here's some additional oddities:

1. When I swap in notepad.exe into the .py instead of my target applications path, notepad launches ok.
2. When I run the script line by line from the CLI (start by launching python, then type out the next 4-5 lines of Python), the script works as expected.

Examples:

```
#This works in the .py, and from the CLI

import subprocess

cmd = ['C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe', 'C:\\temp\\myfiles\\test_24.xml']
pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
pipe.wait()
print(pipe)
```

```
#This fails in the .py, but works ok when pasted in line by line from the CLI

import subprocess

cmd = ['C:\\temp\\temp_app\\target_application.exe', 'C:\\temp\\myfiles\\test_24.xml']
pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
pipe.wait()
print(pipe)
```

The result is no output when running the .py

I've tried several other variants, including the following:

```
import subprocess

tup = 'C:\\temp\\temp_app\\target_application.exe C:\temp\test\test_24.xml'

proc = subprocess.Popen(tup)
proc.wait()
(stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()

print(stdout)
if proc.returncode != 0:
    print("The error is: " + str(stderr))
else:
    print("Executed: " + str(tup))
```

Result:

```
None
The error is: None
1.082381010055542
```

Now this method indicates there is an error because we are returning something other than 0 and printing "The error is: None", and this is because stderror is "None". So - is it throwing an error without giving an error?
stdout is also reporting "None".

So, lets try check_call and see what happens:

```
print("Trying check_call")
    try:
        subprocess.check_call('C:\\temp\\temp_app\\target_application.exe C:\\temp\\test\\test_24.xml', shell=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as error:
        print(error)
```

Results:

```
Trying check_call
Command 'C:\temp\temp_app\target_application.exe C:\temp\test\test_24.xml' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I've additionally tried subprocess.run, although it is missing the wait procedure I was hoping to use.

```
import subprocess

tup = 'C:\\temp\\temp_app\\target_application.exe C:\temp\test\test_24.xml'

proc = subprocess.run(tup, check=True)
proc.wait()
(stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()

print(stdout)
if proc.returncode != 0:
    print("The error is: " + str(stderr))
else:
    print("Executed: " + str(tup))
```

What reasons might be worth chasing, or what other ways of trying to catch an error might work here? I don't know how to interpret "`" as an error result.

Comment: I don't think it solves your problem, but `shell=True` is redundant on Windows if you are just running a separate binary as a subprocess.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't solve the issue, but a good heads up.

Comment: What do you expect `print(pipe)` to print? `pipe` is the name of the `Popen` object, not any result from the subprocess.

Comment: You're right. I'm hoping to catch any errors so I can see what's going wrong.

Comment: I'm guessing replacing all this with `subprocess.run()` will solve it regardless of where the precise problem is. As the documentation already tells you, avoid `Popen` where the higher-level functions do what you want. (Pass the keyword argument `check=True` to get an exception if the subprocess fails.)

Comment: I did initially try using Run but was having the same sorts of issues. I forgot about that here - I first tried a few days ago. Incidentally, the reason I went to Popen was that I spotted ```For more advanced use cases, the underlying Popen interface can be used directly``` in the documentation, and then saw that I could use wait() to check for the child finishing (which is kind of important to me in the broader context).

Comment: ```proc = subprocess.run(tup, check=True)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'C:\temp\temp_app\target_application.exe C:\temp\test\test_7.xml' returned non-zero exit status 1. ``` Still with the exit code of 1.

Comment: You can also try os.system

Comment: Yes, you said you wanted to trap errors? Put that in a `try: ... expept CalledProcessError:` to handle the exception. But that also looks like you passed a single string instead of a tuple or list. Probably also add `text=True` and `capture_output=True` if you want to capture the output, and expect it to be textual.

Comment: You want to use `Popen` when you _don't_ want to `wait`; that is by and large the only common use case `run` is not suitable for.

Comment: Perhaps see also my currently highest-voted answer which attempts to provide context for what's in the `subprocess` documentation. It's a non-Windows answer primarily, but significant parts of it applies to Windows, too.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee. I suspect I've managed to trap the most immediate error, and so have some remedial work to do before I can fully test any of these suggestions further regarding what function is better for running external processes. Those pointers will be important to me, I'm sure.  Thank you for the context.

Comment: I'm not in a place where I can test (and even when I am, I fortunately don't have Windows) but running `wait` before `communicate` is probably what botches your `Popen` attempt. But in case it's not already obvious, `run` includes `wait` as part of what it does, so again, propably simply go with that.